# When might 2 phase commit not make progress?

Tags: distributed-system

When might 2 phase commit block so that it is no longer making progress?

Assume Coordinator and 4 participants here.

Suppose that participant P2 crashes just after sending the "vote-commit" message (i.e. this message is successfully received by the coordinator) and there are no further failures, then Coordinator waits for "Ack" from P2 and continuously sends "Global-commit" to it after timeouts. The coordinator is blocked; Other participants are not blocked.

Is there any other case?

Answer (score 0):

2 phase commit does not work if any message is delayed or dropped, or if any participant crashes (stops responding) at any time.

There are a few different ways 2PC can fail. Here are some I found using [Molly](https://github.com/palvaro/molly).

- The coordinator can crash after sending the `vote-commit` message, but before sending the `global-commit`/`global-abort`. This means all clients that voted to commit are stuck waiting for a response from the coordinator.
- The network might delay or drop `global-commit` messages, causing the recipients of those messages to block, waiting for a message they might never receive.
- The network might delay or drop votes to commit or abort, causing the coordinator to block, waiting for message(s) it might never receive.
- The network might delay or drop queries, i.e. the messages that the coordinator sends to the other participants, asking them if they are ready to commit or not. The coordinator will then block, waiting for responses from these participants.